# Copy and increase formula range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a formula which uses the following:

```
=MOD(COUNTIF(H4:H5, H5), COUNTIF('Track Host Train'!$E$3:$E$9, H5) )
```

This works as I need to but when I copy this to subsequent rows, I would want the H4:H5 row to increase in its range size rather than just copy across. So for example, if I copied the formula to row 100, I'd like it to say (H4:H100) rather than (H99:H100).

Is there a way I can achieve this or would I have to use a Google Script?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your H4 by `H$4` or `$H$4`, it will lock the number 4